# ZSH extends bash autocompletion

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command-line, zsh

It's possible to make ZSH extends bash autocompletion? Bash can autocomplete almost every command in the system, and in ZSH i always need to enable a plugin for it.

Here is an example (ignore the warnings, are from custom scripts that don't work in bash)

[image: Bash autocompletion]

Comment: I don't know if zsh has a built-in auto-completion. All I can advice you is use a plugin...

Comment: This isn't on-topic here; Stack Overflow is exclusively for questions about _developing software_. Consider [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [unix.se] for questions about interacting with UNIX tools as a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can install the project zsh-completions

(https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions)

**From Ubuntu packages**

```
echo "deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/shells:/zsh-users:/zsh-completions/xUbuntu_19.10/ /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/shells:zsh-users:zsh-completions.list
curl -fsSL https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/shells:zsh-users:zsh-completions/xUbuntu_19.10/Release.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/shells:zsh-users:zsh-completions.gpg > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt install zsh-completions
```

**From Gitub repository**

- Clone the repository:

```
git clone git://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions.git
```

- Include the directory in your $fpath, for example by adding in ~/.zshrc:

```
fpath=(path/to/zsh-completions/src $fpath)
```

- You may have to force rebuild zcompdump:

```
rm -f ~/.zcompdump; compinit
```